# html5 video custom controls in IE full screen mode?

Tags: html, html5-video, internet-explorer-11, html5-fullscreen

I'm trying to implement custom video controls with JS. I'm able to get it work on the Firefox, Chrome and IE. But in the IE11 when a user went to fullscreen mode the custom control bar is not visible.

Please help me.

Comment: try to call the requestFullscreen methods on the video container so yuo can ensure that the element's children, e.g. the custom controls, go fullscreen also.